# how can I make my jquery animation smoother?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I am building a social network site and I have high demands out of it so I need a little help in making the animation better and smoother. I have to admit I am a backend developer, not really doing much frontend stuff but this is what I got: I have a button and when the user presses the button I need to show the user a nice form. I have been working on a animation for this http://jsfiddle.net/bTZ5D/1/ . I find it ok, but not really WOW material, if anyone can make it better or suggest how to make it better I would appreciate it.
This is my js code:

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('body').on('click', '#ask-question', function() {
        var container = $('.ask-question-wrapper');

        $(this).fadeOut('fast', function() {
            $(this).hide();
            container.show();
            container.animate({ height: "265px" }).animate({  
               height: "245px" });;

        });
    });
})
```

Comment: what do you mean by better?  something like this? [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wirey00/vMQdh/)

Comment: I mean smoother, from a frontend developer point of view, much more fluid, I feel like mine is a little clunky

Comment: did you check out my fiddle above?  Just play around with the speed if you want.  I'm not completely sure because this is a very vague question.

Comment: yes I checked it :) thx for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Additionally you can also use a easing library.

Or a kind of opacity animating:

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('body').on('click', '#ask-question', function() {
        var container = $('.ask-question-wrapper');

        container.css('opacity', '0');

        $(this).fadeOut('fast', function() {
            $(this).hide();
            container.show();
            container.animate({ height: "265px",
                                opacity: 1}).animate({  
            height: "245px" });

        });
    });
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zp6fA/

Answer (score 1):

> smoother

Using the code posted by **wirey** and `('slow')`: http://jsfiddle.net/MfdBw/

Answer (score 0):

Simply use [jQuery**Ui**](http://jqueryui.com/show/) and add some options to show, like `container.show('clip');`